# Showing any linear operator $T : X \to Y$ is bounded, where $X$ is a finite dimensional normed vector space, and $Y$ any normed vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a ﬁnite dimensional normed vector space and $Y$ an arbitrary normed vector space. Show that any linear operator $T : X \to Y$ is bounded.

I got the hint to first show that $\| x\|_0 := \| x \| + \| Tx\|$, $x \in X$, deﬁnes a norm on $X$, but I do not know how this should help me.

Further I should calculate $\|T\|$ for where $X = K^n$, equipped with the Euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|_2$, $Y := \ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ and $Tx := (x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots) \in \ell_1(\mathbb{N})$, for all $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in K^n$.

Can please someone help?

Comment: Hint: What theorem do you know about norms on a finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent?

Comment: Yes! So what can you infer, if you know that the original norn and the one you defined are equivalent?

Comment: $∥Tx∥ \leq  ∥x∥ + ∥Tx∥ =  ∥x∥_0$

Comment: Not quite, but close. $\|x\|+\|Tx\|$ is not equal to the original norm, it is bounded by some constant $C$ times the original norm. The result is rather the same though.

Comment: This is what I want to show $∥Tx∥_Y\leq C ∥x∥_X$. So
 $∥Tx∥_Y\leq ∥x∥_Y +∥Tx∥_Y = ∥x∥_X +∥Tx∥_X = ∥x∥_0 \leq C∥x∥_0 $.?

Comment: I am sorry, I must have misunderstood your first comment and confused you further. You do have $\|Tx\| \leq \|x\|_0$, thus the operator is bounded.

Comment: Yes I was confused :-) thank you

Comment: Note that you can infer that “the operator is bounded” without further precision only because all norms on $X$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the operator norm:
I was thinking

$ ||T∥_2 = \sup \limits_{x \neq 0} \frac{∥Tx∥_1}{∥x∥_1} =  \sup \limits_{x \neq0} \frac{∥(
x_1,…,x_n,0,0,…)∥_1}{∥(x_1,…,x_n)∥_1} = \sup \limits_{x \neq0} \frac{|x_1|+…+|x_n|}{|x_1|+…+|x_n|}= 1 $

Comment: Seems correct !

Comment: Why are you using the $1$ norm for $x$ if $X$ is equipped with the Euclidean norm?

Comment: Because $Y := \ell_1(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: But for $x$ you have to look at the norm of $X$. You should use the norm of $Y$ just for $Tx$

Comment: True. So $ ||T∥_2 = \sup \limits_{x \neq 0} \frac{∥Tx∥_1}{∥x∥_2} =  \sup \limits_{x \neq0} \frac{∥(
x_1,…,x_n,0,0,…)∥_1}{∥(x_1,…,x_n)∥_2} = \sup \limits_{x \neq0} \frac{|x_1|+…+|x_n|}{(|x_1|^2+…+|x_n|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}= ? $
and I thought I had figured it out